# Use ISNULL on sub-select aggregate expression and return empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following sub-select expression inside my query. What I want to do is wrap the entire aggregate expression with an ISNULL function, and when a NULL is encountered I want it to return an empty string ('').

I tried running the below but I get Varchar to Numeric conversion error because the empty string is varchar, but the expression is being calculated numerically.

```
SELECT PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID, PS_PO_LINE.PO_DT,

ISNULL((SELECT  SUM (PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.AMT_ORDERED)
FROM PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW WHERE PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.BUSINESS_UNIT=PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT AND  
PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.PO_ID=PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID AND PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.LINE_NBR=PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR 
AND PS_PO_LINE.AMT_ONLY_FLG = 'Y' ), '')  AS "AMOUNT"

FROM PS_PO_LINE PS_PO_LINE
```

I don't want to return an 0 if the NULL function evaluates to True, I would rather return '' instead. Is this possible?

Comment: Try a case statement that says CASE WHEN xxx IS NULL THEN '' ELSE sum(value) END

Comment: `ISNULL` forces the **second** parameter into the first parameter's type. Don't just do `CASE` or `COALESCE`, do an explicit `CAST/CONVERT` to varchar on the first result

Comment: @Charlieface Should the CONVERT be inside the SUM function? i.e. ISNULL((SELECT SUM(CONVERT((VARCHAR, PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.AMT_ORDERED ))

Comment: No, outside, you can't sum a string. Although I find it strange that you would want to do this at all, what's wrong with `null`? By the way you should quote column names with `[]` not `""`, and preferably not use column names that require quoting anyway

Comment: It's being used as a data conversion upload and the vendor requires it to be blank if there it not a non-zero value. Yes I switched it to `ISNULL(( SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR ,SUM (PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.QTY_ORDERED) ) .... `  works great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Charlieface is right: ISNULL forces the second parameter into the first parameter's type.
Maybe try this

```
SELECT PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID, PS_PO_LINE.PO_DT,

ISNULL(CAST((SELECT  SUM (PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.AMT_ORDERED)
FROM PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW WHERE PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.BUSINESS_UNIT=PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT AND  
PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.PO_ID=PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID AND PS_PO_LN_ORDER_VW.LINE_NBR=PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR 
AND PS_PO_LINE.AMT_ONLY_FLG = 'Y' ) AS VARCHAR, '')  AS "AMOUNT"

FROM PS_PO_LINE PS_PO_LINE
```